# Water/ moisture coming through patched concrete hole in basement floor

Tags: concrete, basement, floor, moisture

[image]

We had our walls braced last summer and the basement guys had to drill holes in the floor to push the walls back in to place. They patched up the holes with concrete and I've noticed a few times (almost immediately after) those patched holes were a bit moist and today discovered one of the holes has pooled a small bit of water around it. Quick google search indicates that since concrete is porous this can happen especially if you live in a humid area (we live in WI and it's been a super humid summer - today is exceptionally humid and muggy)

The rest of the floor was previously sealed so I'm guessing this is why it's only happening in the areas they drilled and patched? What's the best course of action here? Our dehumidifier hasn't been working it seems like (runs but not doing anything) so was already planning to buy a new one this weekend. Other that that I'm thinking we should just re-seal those areas with waterproof concrete floor sealer? Should that solve the issue or it there something more we need to do?

Our basement is pretty cool on average even in the hot/humid summer and with our dehumidifier not working it's just been getting increasingly more damp feeling down there. (I didn't notice how bad until I was re-organizing the basement the last few days).

I already called and left a message for our contractors who worked on the basement last year asking why this would happen, what we need to do and if this covered under the warranty. We just had new drain tile put in along 1 wall and 2 walls excavated & brace less than a year ago so I know it's not coming from the walls.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it happening specifically after rain? Or anytime?

Comment: I'm not really sure? It hasn't rained much the last week or so here - today it's been sunny but MUGGY. I just inspected some of the other patched holes and they're totally dry. This one is closest to where we just put in new drain tile and had the walls excavated which seems odd?

Comment: I should specify to - this is NOT a large amount of water. The picture makes it look bigger than it is - the hole that was patched is probably just slightly larger than a half dollar and the water just barely dampened the wash cloth.

Comment: There two ways you can get water, one is simple condensation very similar to what happens in the outside of a glass filled with an icy cold beverage—it water in the air that condenses on the cold concrete.  The other way you can get water is if the water table or possibly the drain tile is causing water to actually be pushed up through the patch from below.  I’m guess it’s the second, and that has little to do with cool basements and more to do with drainage issues.

Comment: If they had to push and brace the basement walls in that way, it is typically because water pressure on the outside is pushing the walls.  Unless they solved the water problem, your basement is basically a boat.  Water will find its way in at any weak spot, and you can't seal it with interior paint or coatings.  It sounds like the water table is much higher than the basement floor, and your floor drain isn't adequate to drain all the water around and under your house.  The work the contractor did was likely needed, but not a good enough solution, and didn't address the underlying problem.

Comment: I apologize in advance as I'm not very savvy when it comes to these sort of things so if my questions seems silly or obvious I'm sorry. Is that something the contractor should have noticed when they tore up the basement floor along the wall (1-1.5 ft out from the wall) and installed new drain tile? We paid close to $20,000 less than a year ago to have this project completed and no one mentioned anything regarding the water table being too high. If that was an issue we would have had it addressed then vs now potentially having to bring someone back out within a year.